# Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I am get an awkward error at ExecuteNonQuery in the second last row.

Errormassage:

> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "sp_InsertShuttleCount": 
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.FormatException: 
>      at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>      at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      at AtsProcedures.InsertShuttleErrorCount(SqlString shuttle, SqlString stations, SqlString errorstations, SqlString nests, SqlString errornests, SqlDateTime ts)
>   .

Stacktrace:

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at ATS_Test_Data_Generator.Form1..ctor() in C:\Code\ATSBDE\c#\Generate Data\ATS_Test_Data_Generator\ATS_Test_Data_Generator\Form1.cs:line 113
>      at ATS_Test_Data_Generator.Program.Main() in C:\Code\ATSBDE\c#\Generate Data\ATS_Test_Data_Generator\ATS_Test_Data_Generator\Program.cs:line 18
>      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

The Values of the Strings

Station: 0;5;10;15;20;30;35;40;55;60;65;70;80;85;90;100;110;120;125;

Errorstations: 5;3;4;4;6;6;4;5;4;4;6;4;4;5;5;4;5;3;5;

Nests: 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;

ErrorNests: 0|1|1|0|1|1|1|0;1|0|1|0|0|1|0|0;0|1|0|0|0|1|1|1;1|0|1|0|1|0|1|0;1|1|1|0|1|1|1|0;1|1|0|1|0|1|1|1;1|1|1|1|0|0|0|0;0|1|1|1|1|0|0|1;1|1|0|0|0|1|1|0;0|0|0|1|1|0|1|1;0|1|1|1|0|1|1|1;1|0|0|1|0|1|0|1;0|0|1|1|1|0|0|1;1|1|1|0|1|1|0|0;0|1|0|1|1|0|1|1;0|1|1|0|1|1|0|0;1|1|0|1|0|1|0|1;0|1|0|0|1|0|1|0;1|1|1|0|0|0|1|1;

D is a Datetime:        d.ToString()    "10.02.2012 06:01:00"   string

The Stored Procedure takes 4 Nvarchar(4000) and one Datetime values

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 16; i++) {
    String Stations="";
    String ErrorStations = "";
    String Nests = "";
    String ErrorNests = "";

    command = new SqlCommand(null, connection) {
        CommandText = "ats.sp_getStations",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    int k = 0;
    while (reader.Read()) {
        Stations += reader.GetInt32(0)+";";
        Nests += "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8;";
        int m=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int l;
            l=r.Next(0, 2);
            nestcounts[i, k, j] += l;
            m += l;

            if(j!=7)
                ErrorNests += nestcounts[i, k, j]  + "|";
            else
                ErrorNests += nestcounts[i, k, j]  + ";";
        }

        stationcounts[i, k] += m;
        ErrorStations += stationcounts[i, k] + ";";
        k++;
    }
    reader.Close();
    command.Dispose();

    command = new SqlCommand(null, connection) {
        CommandText = "exec dbo.sp_InsertShuttleCount @shuttle, @stations, @errorstations, @nests, @errornests, @ts",
    };

    command.Parameters.Clear();
    command.Parameters.Add("@shuttle", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = "1";
    command.Parameters.Add("@stations", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = Stations;
    command.Parameters.Add("@errorstations", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = ErrorStations;
    command.Parameters.Add("@nests", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = Nests;
    command.Parameters.Add("@errornests", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = ErrorNests;
    command.Parameters.Add("@ts", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = d;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    command.Dispose();
}
```

Stored Procedure

It's a CLR Procedure wich works fine, since it's used frequently. And there are of course 5 Nvarchars that was a typo.

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertShuttleCount]
    @shuttle nvarchar,
    @stations nvarchar,
    @errorstations nvarchar,
    @nests nvarchar,
    @errornests nvarchar,
    @ts [datetime]
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [ats-clr].[AtsProcedures].[InsertShuttleErrorCount]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFile', @value=N'AtsProcedures.cs' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'sp_InsertShuttleCount'
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFileLine', @value=N'51' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'sp_InsertShuttleCount'
GO

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure as well.  There might be an issue there.

Comment: Yes. And it takes 4 nvarchars and 1 datetime, or was that a typo? You call it with 6 arguments, 5 of which are nvarchars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I i had problems with the semicolon at the end of each string...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably with `reader.GetInt32(0)`. You're most likely hitting a value that doesn't parse properly. Try examining the value of reader[0] when the error occurs. Also bear in mind that GetInt32 will fail if it hits a NULL value in the database. If you have NULLs call `reader.IsDBNUll(0)` first with an appropriate if condition.